# MVCMailer smtp mailsettings set configuration settings programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, smtpclient, mvcmailer

MVCMailer uses the smtp settings from the web.config file as follows:

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
      <smtp from="some-email@gmail.com">
        <network enableSsl="true" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="some-email@gmail.com" password="valid-password" />
      </smtp>
</mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Controller:

```
public virtual MvcMailMessage Welcome()
{
    //ViewBag.Data = someObject;
    return Populate(x => {
              x.ViewName = "Welcome";
              x.To.Add("some-email@example.com");
              x.Subject = "Welcome";
        });
}
```

Is there anyway to set the SMTP settings in code? I want to avoid saving the password in the web.config file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Call `SmtpClientWrapper` with a SmtpClient that has the properties you need.

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mail.example.com", 995);
SmtpClientWrapper wrapper = new SmtpClientWrapper(client);
```

Comment: I still an error that the SMTP host wasn't specified when doing this...I think I need to find a way to assign the wrapper to MVCMailer.

Comment: Ah ok I figured this out - you need to pass the wrapper to the Send method. Thanks :)